# Putting JMEcanvas into JPanel SWING

Tags: swing, jmonkeyengine

I need to put a JME canvas into my app JPanel.

In the class with JME I init this:

```
public JmeCanvasContext ctx;
public Dimension dim = new Dimension(800, 600);
private void init() {
    AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(true);
    settings.setWidth(dim.width);
    settings.setHeight(dim.height);
    // settings.setRenderer(AppSettings.LWJGL_OPENGL1);

    setSettings(settings);
    createCanvas(); // create canvas!
    ctx = (JmeCanvasContext) getContext();
    ctx.setSystemListener(this);

    ctx.getCanvas().setPreferredSize(dim);
    startCanvas();

}
```

Then, in my main Window I create a JPanel (using NEtbeans designer tool) and add my jme canvas to the panel.

```
PanelDelAgente.add(agenteMolon.ctx.getCanvas());
```

But doesntwork. Is the first time that I use JME and I dont know very well how can I put it in a Jpanel

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use https://github.com/davidB/jme3_ext_swing

The question was also posted on the JME forum : https://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/putting-jme-canvas-into-jpanel-swing , with more answers.